# Ghostscript Error when doing multiple slices with pst-solides3d

Tags: pstricks, ghostscript, pst-solides3d

I'm trying to represent a polytope, but it seems that GhostScript doesn't let me slice a cube more than once. In particular, I tried the following:

```
\psset{unit=0.6cm,labelsep=20pt}
\psset{viewpoint=150 -110 10 rtp2xyz,Decran=120} 
\begin{pspicture*}(-5,-1)(15,20) 
  \psset{solidmemory}
  \psSolid[object=cube,action=none,a=10,plansepare={[1 1 1 -3]},name=A](5,5,5)
  \psSolid[object=load,load=A0,plansepare{[1 1 0 -2]},action=none,name=B]
  \psSolid[object=load,load=B,action=draw**]
  \composeSolid
  \axesIIID[axisnames={A,B,C}](0,0,0)(11,11,11) 
\end{pspicture*}
```

The above code compiles but of course shows only the result from the first cut. If I replace the last `\psSolid` line with

```
  \psSolid[object=load,load=B0,action=draw**]
```

then GhostScript fails and gives me the following error:

```
Output written on dual_example.dvi (1 page, 36936 bytes).
SyncTeX written on dual_example.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on dual_example.log.
### /usr/texbin/dvips -R -Poutline  -o /tmp/altpdflatex.14198-1361245018/dual_example.ps dual_example.dvi
This is dvips(k) 5.992 Copyright 2012 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2013.02.18:1936' -> /tmp/altpdflatex.14198-1361245018/dual_example.ps
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/dvips/base/tex.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-algparser.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-tools.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pst-dots.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/dvips/pst-node/pst-node.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/dvips/pst-solides3d/pst-solides3d.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/dvips/base/texps.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/dvips/base/special.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/dvips/base/color.pro>. 
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi12.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
[1] 
### ps2pdf13 /tmp/altpdflatex.14198-1361245018/dual_example.ps /tmp/altpdflatex.14198-1361245018/dual_example.pdf
Error: /undefined in B0
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1894   1   3   %oparray_pop   1893   1   3   %oparray_pop   1877   1   3   %oparray_pop   1771   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1157/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:113/200(L)--   --dict:751/1012(L)--   --dict:182/300(L)--   --dict:38/200(L)--   --dict:203/300(L)--   --dict:751/1012(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
Current file position is 419337
GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
### FAILED to generate /tmp/altpdflatex.14198-1361245018/dual_example.pdf ()
```

Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue which cannot be reproduced with an up-to-date TeX system.


Comment: I've just tested this with TeX Live 2013 on Windows and everything looks OK. I'd say this is a version issue, probably a bug in GhostScript, so updating would be my advice.

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply – somehow my email notifications don't seem to work. Anyways, I have updated my TeX Live to 2013 as well and am assuming I have the latest GhostScript since I just bought a new MacBook pro – but the problem persists.

According to the console output (which is too long to print), I have TeX Live 2013 and GhostScript 9.07, on a Mac OSX 10.9 (in TeXShop).